# Fill String[] with lines from .txt in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display random lines from `temp.txt` file in Android.

This is my code that generates text:

```
String quote[] ={"a","b","c"};

public void makeQuote(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(quote.length);
    textQuot.setText(quote[num]);
}
```

This solution works and gives me a random output of what is inside the String array.

Now I tried to fill the `String[]` with text from `temp.txt` file like this:

```
AssetManager manager = getAssets();
InputStream in = manager.open("temp.txt");
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(in,"UTF-8");

String quote[] = lines.toArray(new String[0]);

public void makeQuote(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(quote.length);
    textQuot.setText(quote[num]);
}
```

But the App just crashes at start.
Basically I just want to show random lines from `temp.txt` file and try to do so by filling a String Array with these lines.

Also I have this code, but I don't know how to pass to `makeQuote()` method and to generate random content from the file.

```
private List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader buff = null;
    try {
        buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("temp.txt"), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            quotes.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (buff != null) {
            try {
                buff.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return quotes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## File location

You can put your file in `raw` directory in `assets`, so path for it should be like there:

```
/app/src/main/res/raw/temp.txt
```

After that you can access to this file using:

```
R.raw.temp
```

## Code modification

Only on thing you have to change is line:

```
buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("temp.txt"),"UTF-8"));
```

which you have to replace with:

```
buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.temp), "UTF-8"));
```

where instead of:

```
getAssets().open("temp.txt")
```

you use:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.temp)
```

## How to get random quote

1) Fetch all `quotes` from file (from `res/raw/`)

2) Check, if all quotes have been read correctly (so your list is NOT empty)

3) Draw a number (from correct range!)

4) Get element from list which is on the drawn position

```
List<String> quotes = getQuotes();

if (!quotes.isEmpty()) {
    int randomPosition = new Random().nextInt(quotes.size());
    String quote = quotes.get(randomPosition);
}
```

## Random

Code

```
new Random().nextInt(20);
```

returns you one random value from range:

```
0 .. 19
```

Position inside the list (or arrays) starts from `0`, so we can use `quotes.size()`, because it return value from range:

```
0 ... quotes.size()-1
```

Comment: How do I fill in this content in a String array to output a random line from the .txt - file?

Comment: I will report back in a few days. Currently just copy and pasted the .txt in a String array

Comment: @Livelife ok, waiting for feedback :)